# Quickly, syntax error: media_grid.show()

Tags: 11.10, application-development, quickly

i run the app and get this error.
the little arrow points to the 'd', dont know what that means. 
plus i had the same error just before but on this line:

```
from quickly.widgets.dictionary grid import DictionaryGrid
```

the arrow pointed to the 'd' in grid as well. then i changed it to this:

```
from quickly.widgets.dictionary_grid import DictionaryGrid
```

i added a '_' in the middle. and now i have the syntax error in the question.

Thanks for any help that is given!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/simple-player", line 32, in <module>
    import simple_player
  File "/home/alex/simple-player/simple_player/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from simple_player import SimplePlayerWindow
  File "/home/alex/simple-player/simple_player/SimplePlayerWindow.py", line 51
    media_grid.show()
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install python-quickly.widgets`
`python`
`from quickly.widgets.dictionary_grid import DictionaryGrid`
reports success

if you're getting a syntax error you should correct your indentation.  the tutorial is right, you should actually follow it.

Comment: ok, now. what about the one in the question? media_grid.show()

Comment: you should edit you question body to contain what fails.  like the actual code that fails

Comment: the copy and paste version is different than the tutorial